# How to apply like query in JpaRepository on List of String

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

I am using JpaRepository and I am trying to query into DB using `List<String>` so I am using like query for the same and I am not getting any results.

Here is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM MappingEntity a WHERE UPPER(a.cuisines) LIKE (% :cuisine_type %) AND ST_distance(ST_POINT(:lng , :lat), a.geoLocation) < :radius")
List<OpentableMappingEntity> getRestaurantsListCuisines1(@Param("cuisine_type") List<String> cuisines, @Param("lat") double latitude, @Param("lng") double longitude, @Param("radius") Integer radius);

@Query("SELECT a FROM MappingEntity a WHERE UPPER(a.cuisines) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:cuisine_type, '%')) AND ST_distance(ST_POINT(:lng , :lat), a.geoLocation) < :radius")
List<OpentableMappingEntity> getRestaurantsListCuisines2(@Param("cuisine_type") List<String> cuisines, @Param("lat") double latitude, @Param("lng") double longitude, @Param("radius") Integer radius);
```

I tried both the query and I am getting an empty response if I remove the like part it will give me the results.

How to apply like query on List?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE with a list, instead use IN

Example: a native query with a list:

```
SELECT * FROM order AS o WHERE o.fol IN ('OCV3', 'OCV5', 'OPL8');
```

And a query in the repository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM order AS o WHERE o.fol IN :list", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Order> stack(@Param("list") List<String> list);
```

Both querys show the same results